# webGL image canvas out of range error on mobile devices

Tags: canvas, webgl, cesiumjs

I've got an app using Cesiumjs which allows a user to add an image or text (which is converted to an image) to the canvas.
Everything is fine on desktop environments, but on mobile devices I get the following error :  `WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: width or height out of range`

Research points to this being due to the canvas not having a width or height defined. But, of course, I don't know the height or width the canvas should be as I'm accepting content from the user.

Looking at browser stats, I see that desktop chrome has a `MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` of 16384 compared to chrome on android having only 4096.

How can I use this information to fix the issue and provide the correct height and width to the canvas (if that is what is needed) which will not cut-off the image but will be within the MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE bounds?

Comment: @NikolaLukic unfortunately, settings width and height to 256 returns `glCopyTexSubImage2D: bad dimension` error. I've tried other sizes and still seeing the same errors and behavior

Comment: You will need to found someone with cesiumjs background. Is it from canvas2d to the glTexture ? Mobile variant of webGL is still iceberg ... Put 'cesiumjs' like tag for this question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an acceptable size on mobile devices, I had to use
`width = img.width \ Cesium.defaultValue(window.devicePixelRatio, 1.0);`